# Intellij Idea - How To Perform Action On Multiple Classes Together

Tags: intellij-idea

I have multiple Java POJOs and I want to generate equals, hashCode and toString methods using Intellij's autogenerate feature in all classes together.

How can I perform this action on multiple classes together as a bulk action. I do not want to perform this on classes individually.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question since you asked it?

Comment: @FrançoisDupire nope.

Comment: I'm curious about why did you need this. Do you have a lot of existing POJO in your codebase that are missing these?

As a side note, this might not always be the best thing to do in an existing codebase as legacy code might depend on the implicit implementations of these methods.

Comment: @mindreader I didn't find a way to do this. I ended up using Lombok.